# T-SQL Determining Nouns and Verbs in String Text

Tags: sql, vb.net, t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2, vb.net-2010

Converting an application from one development platform to VB.NET / SQL Server.

User has some functionality where they can type in a phrase and a database search on text will be done.

Maintainer of the original code is unable (or unwilling) to give me any logic or code currently utilized.

One of my user contacts tells me that the "search mechanism" determines the verbs in the phrase and works from there.

We are using SQL Server 2008 R2. We are not allowed to use CLR code.
Does anyone know of any way to determine PARTS OF SPEECH using T-SQL?

If I had SQL Server 2012 I'd use the Fuzzy Search to do this work, but we don't.

==========

UPDATE:
Although I don't do a noun/verb/parts of speech look up my current method for doing Dictionary/Phrase look ups is based on keywords and does the following...

I split the phrase being searched for into keywords.

I search my dictionary (terms and examples) or ANY word in the search term list using a Like.

With Those Candidates, I do a set of counts.  I count the number of EXACT matches on my original phrase, then count the number of matching keywords.

Finally I use a T-SQL Levenshtein algorithm to calculate "difference distance".

I then return the matches in order by total match count/ Levenshtein value.

It's the "best" I can do...

Comment: No, that is absolutely not possible.  Sorry.

Comment: Maybe you can do some [pattern matching](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187489%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) with tsql [pathindex](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188395.aspx) (limited regular expression) but I don't know a pattern to extract english verbs...

Comment: Dogs have a lot of trouble with parts of speech. I think that "walk" is an active verb, they think it's a noun. Just an opportunity to exchange little yellow sticky notes. (3M just changed the name from Pissed-it to Post-it and acted like they invented the idea.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could probably use a bloom filter to do this...

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bloom_filter

Bloom filter can be used as a mechanism for spell checker and correction. It works by identifying words (in you string) with words in a dictionary... for instance, your dictionary would contain verbs

here is al list of Verbs for instance that you would store in your [Bloom Filter] dictionary

http://www.worldclasslearning.com/english/five-verb-forms.html

then they would be matched to words in your string.......

I have an example on my web site, but when I last checked the site today the server was down. As soon as its available again I'll post a link to an example and demo...

in the mean time, here is an example, it's written in C# though.....

https://gist.github.com/richardkundl/8300092

OK, so my web site is up again... here is a link to a VB example of a Bloom Filter. its a console demo to illustrate how a bloom filter works...

http://gsidev.somee.com/#3&84335AB075764976B53A90E9B1522000&vb

Here is a link to a small VB.net and C# demo applications the use a winform control that I created.... there is a demo video too....

http://gsidev.somee.com/#4&F69A67EE2E44492EA53A9537FD94F3FD&info

You can essentially reverse the logic that identifies 'correctly' spelt words to instead identify Verbs OR Nouns.... THEN, rather than having a dictionary of every word (as you would do with a spell checker) you would simply have a dictionary of Verbs OR Nouns...

As far as speed goes, a Bloom Filter is pretty efficient if you tweak it right, even with dictionaries of 10000s of words, it DOESN'T simply compare a given string with a list of strings (that would take forever)... it's a bit more complicated than that.... The theory is that a given word is "possibly in set" or "definitely not in set" i.e. 'It might be spelt correctly OR it most definitely isn't spelt correctly' sounds a bit wishy washy but in actual fact is extremely accurate  about 97% - 98% of the time......

Comment: that looks interesting. I might be able to utilize this in a Version2. I'd be interested to see your example on the website.

Comment: Unfortunately my web site is still not up and running. However, I will let you know as soon as it is, I still have my code though and am in the process of modifying it to identify nouns and verbs as well as spell-check... it is a Winforms component that 'plugs' into a richTextBox and checks the Spelling as you type,

Comment: Web site is back up.... have modified my answer to include new links to demo and code..... Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks @Monty I'll take a look.